# Gitlab.com: How to restrict/allow repositories view to specific users in a group?

Tags: gitlab

I have repositories under group in Gitlab.com.

I don't want ALL the users to see ALL the repositories of the group, whatever the role.

It seems unbelievable that this isn't possible but I can't remove an user from a repository.

- How can I do that? Creating a subgroup isn't a solution or I'll need to create multiple mirrors in each group just to manage the permission.
- If that's not possible with Gitlab, which cloud platform supports that? GitHub? I don't mind at all changing for that feature.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm obviously **Owner** of the group and all the projects in that group.

Comment: In GitHub, it seems possible to invite specific users for a specific repository in an organization without adding him to the whole organization.

Answer (score 1):

One option is through [project visibility](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html):

> Private projects can only be cloned and viewed by project members (except for guests)

So in that setup/setting, you can remove a user from a project member list.

Comment: Thanks VonC, the group is private (company's group) and all the fields are greyed out. In `Members` of the group's repo/project, everything is greyed out, I can't add/delete user and can't change their role either.

Comment: @Alexis Strange, can you check with an admin of the GitLab instance, just to see if this is related to a permission level?

Comment: It's gitlab.com. I can open an issue for that.